# R: Limit in line width when using pdf()

Tags: r, pdf, igraph

I am trying to reproduce very thin lines with `pdf()` but it seems I reached a limit.

```
require(igraph)

set.seed(28100)
ba <- ba.game(100, directed=FALSE)

lo <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(ba)

pdf("~/Desktop/test.pdf")
plot(ba, layout=lo, vertex.size=1, vertex.label=NA, edge.width=0.1)
dev.off()
```

which produces

[image]

but then when I plot with the same settings

```
tiff("~/Desktop/test.tiff")
plot(ba, layout=lo, vertex.size=1, vertex.label=NA, edge.width=0.1)
dev.off()
```

I correctly get

[image]

Is it possible to reduce the line with in the pdf output?

Comment: Rhetorical question: Can your screen display lines thinner than 1 pixel? Your **PDF viewer** may choose to display lines "too thin to accurately show" as 1 pixel thick lines. If you zoom in (which is not possible with the TIFF version), you will see the lines stay the same – 'as thin as possible' – until they *can* faithfully be reproduced, and only then they'll appear thicker. The line widths stored into the PDF file are correct.

Comment: I think the thickness I see is way bigger than 1 pixel. I compared my PDF file to a different PDF (in the same viewer) which renders much thinner lines (this is the file: http://www.agile-online.org/Conference_Paper/CDs/agile_2012/proceedings/papers/Paper_Comber_Geographic_Analysis_of_Social_Network_Data_2012.pdf on page 2)

Comment: Post your PDF somewhere on a public location and we'll have a look.

Comment: @Jongware https://www.dropbox.com/s/rujfxxldipbj57r/test.pdf?dl=0

Comment: A crude fix: add some transparency to the edges with `edge.color="#00000010"`

Comment: Well, the good news is the lines *are* thin. Strangely enough not the exact value you asked for, but still fairly close: `0.08 w  % set line width`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623689/why-curved-edges-are-invisible-in-igraph-plotting